# ASP.NET MVC3 - Multiple Stored procedures on Single Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

Is it possible to call multiple stored procedures (not multiple result sets from a procedure) and display results on a single page in ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

From what I understand only one Model can created on any single page and my stored procedure is already tied to that Model. I would like to call another procedure and display that result as well on my page

Answer (score 2):

I think the root problem is to understand the meaning of the **Model** in the **MVC pattern**.

First of all,

> **The model consists of application data and business rules**, and the controller mediates input, converting it to commands for the model or view.[3] A view can be any output representation of data, such as a chart or a diagram

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

In ASP.Net MVC you link a *model* to your view, this model **should not be** part of your domain logic or any **domain object**

The real model (using the meaning of the MVC pattern) is represented by your domain objects.

So what should you put inside the object that you link to your view??

These objects should contain a **representation of the view**, in other words simple DTO's containing **only** the data that is going to be used in the view and nothing more. These models should represent the data being used in the view. If you follow this approach, and you need to display more data in the page, you only need to add another property to this *model* and voila, you can use it from your view.

In a CQRS architecture, these DTO's should be populated by the *Query repositories*.

If you do not have a CQRS architecture, just populate these objects in your domain, repositories, etc. Do not do it inside the controller, keep your controllers clean and simple, by making calls to your real domain using services or repositories

Try to avoid the reuse of these DTO's, they should belong to one view only. And do yourself a favor and do not try to reuse a domain object instead of a DTO just to use it as the model.

Following this approach your view-models will be clean, since they will be only DTO's and only containing the data needed by the view. And you can fill these DTO's from different sources, even from different databases if you want.

When you want to perform an action you would read from the model the data provided by the user, and with this data you would call your domain through repositories, services or in a CQRS arc. using commands

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is "yes".

I suggest you do some more research (ie reading articles and looking at sample apps) into MVC and concentrate on understanding these points:

- The **Model** is a class used to group the data you want to display in the **View**.  It can be populated by a variety of methods and does not have to be the domain object or the pure representation of the database result.
- A "page" (the concept of what a user sees in their browser window) can be made up from one or more **Views**.  Each **View** can be responsible for displaying one type of **Model** allowing for reuse, but a "page" can have *multiple* **Views**.
- Models are not "tied" to stored procedures.  Perhaps you are using an ORM tool that returns a DTO class (which you call model)? This doesn't have to be the **Model** used by the **View**.  The **Controller** could compose several of these DTO classes into one **Model** class.
- N-tier application design where database access is separated from the display logic.  MVC tries to encourage this but it still has to be done correctly to avoid tying yourself in knots.

Good luck!